# Can you view AD groups and users when logged in with Seamless Authentication?

Tags: php, windows, apache, active-directory, ldap

**Set-up:** Windows domain with Active directory; web application running on PHP5.3/Apache2.

**Requirement:** Application needs to view groups and users on a specified domain without having to provide username/password (and group them as per business logic).

I looked into seamless authentication - it looks like I can get the user authenticated, but I also need to get the list of groups and users which this mod_auth_sspi doesn't seem to provide.

PHP LDAP provides functionality to view AD tree, but it either a) requires username (can get from SSPI)/password (how can I get it?) to be bound, or b) requires anonymous setup which is disabled by default on post-2k3 domain controllers.

So, how do I get at AD users/groups without having to set up a separate AD account?

Comment: Quick question: It sounds like you're running Apache/PHP on a windows box... Any reason you're not using IIS/ASP? I personally never have a particular preference, but in this case it would possibly make more sense to use ASP or the like, given what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've taken over an existing project which is the way it is - on Windows+Apache and PHP :) Would ASP offer us the solution to my problem?

Comment: To clarify my understanding, is the problem that you cannot access the AD tree because the PHP LDAP functionality won't allow you to use the credentials you are logging in with as the credentials that retrieve the AD tree details?

Comment: No that's not it... I'd like the app to retrieve AD listings without explicitly logging in with a username/password first. PHP LDAP does the AD stuff, but requires username+pass; mod_auth_sspi authenticates you without having to type password, but doesn't do AD afaik - I need some kind of amalgamation of both

Comment: We have another web app running on the network (not PHP) that achieves that (so it must be possible!), but I have no access to it whatsoever...

Comment: I don't think I understand: you don't want to specify any kind of authentication but want to be able to anonymously perform an LDAP lookup to a corporate AD deployment, yet you have already acknowledged that restrict anonymous or the like is enabled in your environment. How do you expect to connect without credentials? You say another application on your network does this, yet you also say you have no access to it, how can you be so sure it is not using some kind of authentication if you do not have any access to it whatsoever....?

Comment: In theory it is possible - use mod_auth_sspi to authenticate, and other technologies (kerberos?) to connect to AD using the logged-in user credentials. But this solution is providing to be too cumbersome/unreliable so I'm abandoning it in favour of simple LDAP solution (where we require user to type in password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the combination of the question and the comments, I don't think you're going to be able to do it- not PHP Specific but the content of the Active Directory tree is privileged information on most networks. You won't be able to get the information unless you are querying Active Directory as a user with rights to view AD data. This is something that should, on any sane network, require more permissions than simple authentication.

The easiest solution is probably to have some stored credentials for your application that you use to query AD. That may well require that you use some kind of secure store for the credential data, and I don't know what is available through PHP for that stuff, though I am sure there is something.

Comment: My conclusion at this point is to lose the SSO and get user to type in password which will allow doing AD listing - this will satisfy the rest of our requirements. Thank you for your time!